# How to send values to a servlet from a jsp which has directly retrieved values from another jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

my motive is  data flow from **modify.jsp** to **modifysummary.jsp** then to **servlet** to update details but i dont want to use scriptlets in my jsp page.

*modify.jsp*

```
<form action="modifysummary.jsp">
<table border="1">

<tr>
<td><label>FirstName</label></td>
<td><input type="text" name="firstname" value="<%=bean.getFirstname() %>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label>Surname</label></td>
<td><input type="text" name="surname"  value="<%=bean.getSurname() %>" ></td>
</tr>

</form>
```

*modifysummary.jsp*

```
<table>
<tr >
<th>Employee Details</th>
</tr>


<tr>
<td>First Name</td>
<td><%=request.getParameter("firstname") %></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Surname</td>
<td><%=request.getParameter("surname") %></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><input type="button" value="BACK" onclick="javascript:history.go(-1)"></td>
<td><input type="submit" value="Modify" name="Modify"></td>
</tr>

</table>
```

i have written this code inside a form,on clicking the modify button the data should go to servlet in a bean but how to do that.

Comment: Try RequestDispatcher, Reference http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html

Comment: @Sivakumar can you explain me in detail. I can use forward function from one servlet to another but not from one jsp to servlet

Comment: Yeah it's possible to use RequestDispatcher from jsp to servlet. FYI: JSP can be compiled into Java Servlets.

Answer (score 1):

i think this is not possible without using scriptlets in your modifysummary.jsp . you must set your username and password into request attributes

```
 using  request.setattribute();
```

and get them in servlet

```
 using  request.getattribute();
```

why you don't want to use scriptlets.

and if you want to use requestdispatcher you have to write all that in scriptlets

Comment: using scriptlets is a bad way of programming more over we cannot handle exceptions  ..i have shown only username password but there is too much .

Comment: i know this is bad way if you don't want to do this you must learn jsp  expression language

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files must read this link